# Getting the value of a selected option in Antd AutoComplete with custom renderer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an Antd AutoComplete control, that is using a custom renderer, very much alike the one in this forked sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/lookup-patterns-certain-category-antd4140-forked-c9cxi

For simplicities sake, let's assume that the rendered Item looks like this:

```
const renderItem = ({ id, name }) => ({
  value: id.toString(),
  label: (
    <div>
      {name}
    </div>
  )
});
```

My goal is to get the text value `{name}` of that `renderItem` instance and use it in the parent component.

The AutoCompletes input value is linked to the actual Input.Search component

```
<AutoComplete
  value={displayedSearchValue}
  dropdownClassName="certain-category-search-dropdown"
  dropdownMatchSelectWidth={500}
  onSelect={handleSelect}
  style={{
    width: 250
  }}
  options={options}
>
  <Input.Search
    size="large"
    placeholder="input here"
    onChange={(e) => setDisplayedSearchValue(e.target.value)}
  />
</AutoComplete>
```

That has the reason, that when you click and select an entry, AntD will dsiplay the `value` of that record. The value in my case must be a unique identifier, or I could simply use the title.

Now, in a flat list, I could simply extract the selected value in the handleSelect and be done with it:

const handleSelect = (value, option) => {
setDisplayedSearchValue(option.label)
}

This would resolve the design-quirk, and the label would be displayed and not the value. Now, with my nested and grouped datasource, the item is actually a component and option.label is no longer a string, but a react component and I have to drill down to get the actual value:

```
const handleSelect = (value, option) => {
    setDisplayedSearchValue(option.label.props.children);
};
```

If the text value has spaces in between, children becomes an array and I have to a `.join('')`, which adds even more complexity. If I change the markup and nest is further down in the dom, I'll have to make amendments to the parent selector again, which is very error prone, as it will become `option.label.props.children.props.children.join('')` very quickly, if the client wants a bit more fizz around the search results

It feels like I am doing something wrong on a fundamental level with react here, to achieve what I want.
So the question is: How can I get a specific property from a child component, when I click on it from a parent component?

Comment: The short answer to your question is: You should avoid having to read anything from a child component. This is rarely ever needed and kind of against the principles of react. I think this is most likely an XY Problem. React applications are about data and you should not need to read data from a component that you provided it with in the first place.

Comment: I guess reading the value from the `option.value` and doing a find on the raw datasource should to the trick to.

Comment: I will craft an answer with a possible solution but to be clear: `options` should only ever be an object containing plain data types, not react elements. If your goal is to render the options differently then you can override that behaviour by providing a component that knows how to render an option.

Comment: That is a solution, that has been provided by the official documetation of AntD: https://codesandbox.io/s/dgj3q

Comment: Yeah, it's poorly documented as the props API clearly states that `options` should be `{ label, value }[]`, but in the example it states that you can also pass `{ label, options }[]`. The api of the `Autocomplete` component is poorly designed as you can either only change the way the input is rendered or how the options are rendered, but not both. I don't really know why they chose this kind of API. It actually makes it harder to do what you want to achieve in a react way.

Comment: I see what you mean. Personally I was shaking my head about some design decisions as well, although my view on the topic of react is still a rather naive one, as I've not been dealing with it for very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the easiest way to achieve it seems to be to simply add an additional property `name` to the item. It will be ignored by antd but you can still access it in the `onSelect` handler:

```
const renderItem = ({ id, name }) => ({
  name,
  value: id.toString(),
  label: (
    <div>
      {name}
    </div>
  ),
});
```

and then in the handler:

```
const handleSelect = (value, option) => setDisplayedSearchValue(option.name);
```